# Priority Preemptive Scheduling of infinite loop tasks

Tags: scheduling, rtos, preemption

There is much of material available regarding priority preemptive scheduling on Google and Stackoverflow, but I am still having confusion regarding scheduling of infinite loop tasks in a priority preemptive scheduling kernel. Let's consider the following case:

An RTOS starts two tasks `T1` and `T2` with priority `50` and `100` respectively. Both tasks look like:

```
void T1()
{
    while(1)
    {
        perform_some_task1();
        usleep(100);
    }
}
```

and

```
void T2()
{
    while(1)
    {
        perform_some_task2();
        usleep(100);
    }
}
```

As far as I understood, the kernel will schedule `T2` because of its higher priority and suspend `T1` because of its lower priority. Now because `T2` is an infinite loop, it will never relinquish CPU to `T1` until some other high priority task preempts `T2`.

BUT, it seems that my understanding is not correct because I have tested the above case in an RTOS and I get output on console printed by both tasks.

Can somebody comment on my understanding on the matter and the actual behavior of RTOS in above case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, both tasks are being suspended once `perform_some_taskN();` have been executed (releasing the resources to be used by another threads). According to the documentation:

> The usleep() function will cause the calling thread to be suspended from execution until either the number of real-time microseconds specified by the argument useconds has elapsed or a signal is delivered to the calling thread and its action is to invoke a signal-catching function or to terminate the process. The suspension time may be longer than requested due to the scheduling of other activity by the system.

BTW, `usleep()` is deprecated (use `nanosleep()` instead) :

> POSIX.1-2001 declares this function obsolete;
>     use nanosleep(2) instead.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of
>     usleep().

Comment: Thanks @Jose, does it mean if I remove usleep() from both tasks, T2 will keep running and will not give up CPU for T1 to be scheduled and executed?

Comment: Yes, it will wait till the highest priority task has been completed (forgive watchdog or any other external factor).

Comment: @Arshan - that depends on what `perform_some_task2()` does.  It may also include a scheduling/blocking call.  Functions that _block_ (e.g. synchronisation, IPC, delay, timer-wait, and yield functions), cause the scheduler to be invoked, and the highest priority non-blocked (i.e. _ready_) function runs.

Comment: POSIX `usleep()` is deprecated - it is possibly that this theoretical RTOS is not POSIX - looks like pseudocode.

Comment: @Clifford I had supposed an old POSIX example. Otherwise, my answer doesn't make sense at all, because `usleep()` might call a blocking task (given that we don't know what `usleep()` does), being not suspended from execution the current highest priority task.

Comment: @JoseFelipe it is a fair assumption that usleep is blocking.  The point about POSIX usleep perhaps better in a comment rather than the answer, but it is not critical IMO, remains a good answer.

Comment: Thank you @Clifford

Comment: @Clifford! yes it was a pseudocode but the answer really helped me clear the concept. AFIK the sleep()/delay() function in most RTOSes does the same as mentioned by Jose in his answer.